# Tkinter Python, get() does not save any entry text. How should I fix it?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter for the GUI for my project (if you type ingredients you want into a textbox, it will return recipes using API.. and so on). I'm trying to save the user input into a variable so that I can use it later. However, the get() function seems like not catching anything. I've read a different post but not sure what I'm doing it wrong. Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as font

# globally declare the expression variable
expression = ""


def getSentence():
    global expression
    # clear the entry fields
    deleteEntryFields()

    # ask a question
    field2.insert(0, 'What do you want to eat? You can express and we will find something for you!')

    expression = v.get()

    return expression


def getIngredients():
    pass

def searchWithSentence(sentence):
    pass

def searchIngredients(ingredients):
    pass

################################################################################
# This is where I'm testing if the user input is saved to a variable expression.
def enter():
    field1.insert(0, str(expression))
    print(expression)
################################################################################


def clear():
    global expression
    expression = ""


def deleteEntryFields():
    field1.delete(0, 'end')
    field2.delete(0, 'end')


# Driver code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create a GUI window
    master = tk.Tk()

    v = tk.StringVar()

    field1 = tk.Entry(master, textvariable=v)
    field2 = tk.Entry(master)

    field1.insert(0, 'Please type here')
    field2.insert(0, 'Results will be shown here.')

    field1.place(x=20, y=20, width=730, height=50)
    field2.place(x=20, y=80, width=730, height=500)

    # set the background colour of GUI window
    master.configure(background="lemon chiffon")

    # set the title of GUI window
    master.title("Recipe Finder")

    # set the configuration of GUI window
    master.geometry("1050x600")

    # set font
    myFont = font.Font(family='Verdana', size=9, weight='bold')

    # Buttons
    button1 = tk.Button(master, text=' What do you feel like eating? ', fg='black', bg='salmon',
                        command=getSentence, height=5, width=30)
    button1.place(x=770, y=100)
    button1['font'] = myFont

    button2 = tk.Button(master, text=' Type the ingredients you have! ', fg='black', bg='orange',
                        command=getIngredients, height=5, width=30)
    button2.place(x=770, y=200)
    button2['font'] = myFont

    Clear = tk.Button(master, text=' CLEAR ', fg='black', bg='white',
                      command=clear, height=5, width=30)
    Clear.place(x=770, y=300)
    Clear['font'] = myFont

    Enter = tk.Button(master, text=' ENTER ', fg='black', bg='white',
                      command=enter, height=5, width=30)
    Enter.place(x=770, y=400)
    Enter['font'] = myFont


# start the GUI
master.mainloop()
```

Previously I was not using StringVar(), but when I did some research, it says it can be one of the ways to get the get() function worked. But nothing happened... How can I effectively get user input and save it to global variable?
Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: ***`deleteEntryFields()`***: If you do `field1.delete(...` before `v.get()`, then you will get nothing.

Comment: But I have text written ("Please type here") in the field previously... So when I clicke a button, I had to clear the field so that I can type something. Otherwise, I have to delete it myself.

Comment: ***I had to clear the field***: Reverse the mentioned two statements, means copy first before deleting.

Comment: @stovfl is right. You are clearing the entries before getting the values. Of course the value after the clearing is empty.

Comment: So how can I clear the field? I want to have text in the entry field "Please type here", so then when I click the button, it clear up. Then I can type something in the text box and it gets saved.

Comment: What's the problem to move `expression = v.get()` before `deleteEntryFields()`?

Comment: Then I still have the text "Please type here" and if I enter something it'd be like "Please type hereI want cheeseburger" unless I manually erase it.. I wanted entry text box to clear automatically once I click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `Entry` itself to contain an explanation what to type?

To make that work you could [`bind`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) a callback that clears the entry to the `<FocusIn>` event.
This will make sure that the entry field is empty when the user wants to type something.

And to be consistent, you would have to restore that text on a `<FocusOut>` event in the case that the user didn't fill in anything.

While this is used in places where screen space is extremely limited, it doesn't feel like good UI design.
A more common method is to put a `Label` with a description *before* the `Entry`.

Comment: Ah yes I thought about label.. I guess it might be better. I will try again! Thank you.

Comment: @sarahkim Might I also suggest using the [`grid`](https://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) geometry manager instead of `place`? That tends to look good without much effort and is easier to modify.

Comment: I used the grid before, but I wanted to have 2 boxes (although one is just to show the result) and I couldn't find the way to do with the grid... So I did with place. But if it's possible I will try to fix it. Thank you for the advice

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but with a grid a widget can extend over multiple rows and/or columns. It's very flexible. You could use `field2.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=4)`. That way you'd have room for the four buttons in column 1, rows 1-4.